# Unable to add mosquitto config file to ECS task :

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, mqtt, amazon-ecs, mosquitto

I have a mosquitto broker running in docker local machine, with some config files. The command I used to run the broker is as shown below

> docker run -it --name mosquittoBroker -p 1884:1884 -p 1883:1883 -v C:/Users/BadhushaAkhthaar/Documents/conf:/etc/mosquitto 377a70d9c469069f41efb1c21f00b8b3a70da80dd80498039f881465d85f0d96

The mosquitto.conf file is located in the path **C:/Users/BadhushaAkhthaar/Documents/conf** of my local system.

It works fine in local system.

I tried to move/host the broker in AWS ECS, as a task, with the configuration as below

```
{
"taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:18008000010:task-definition/finch-mosquitto-td:1",
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "mosquitto",
        "image": "iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth:latest",
        "cpu": 0,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "name": "mosquitto-1883-tcp",
                "containerPort": 1883,
                "hostPort": 1883,
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "appProtocol": "http"
            },
            {
                "name": "mosquitto-1884-tcp",
                "containerPort": 1884,
                "hostPort": 1884,
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "appProtocol": "http"
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "environment": [],
        "environmentFiles": [],
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "sourceVolume": "mosquitto_config",
                "containerPath": "/conf",
                "readOnly": false
            }
        ],
        "volumesFrom": [],
        "ulimits": [],
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
                "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                "awslogs-group": "/ecs/finch-mosquitto-td",
                "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
            },
            "secretOptions": []
        }
    }
],
"family": "finch-mosquitto-td",
"taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::18008000010:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
"executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::18008000010:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
"networkMode": "bridge",
"revision": 1,
"volumes": [
    {
        "name": "mosquitto_config",
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "/etc/mosquitto"
        }
    }
],
"status": "ACTIVE",
"requiresAttributes": [
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
        "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
        "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
    }
],
"placementConstraints": [],
"compatibilities": [
    "EC2"
],
"requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
],
"cpu": "512",
"memory": "512",
"runtimePlatform": {
    "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
    "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
},
"registeredAt": "2023-08-25T09:16:25.570Z",
"registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::18008000010:root",
"tags": []
}
```

I thought the volume's source path in the above JSON is similar to one in the docker command

> docker run -it --name mosquittoBroker -p 1884:1884 -p 1883:1883 -v C:/Users/BadhushaAkhthaar/Documents/conf:**/etc/mosquitto** 377a70d9c469069f41efb1c21f00b8b3a70da80dd80498039f881465d85f0d96

And also I created a /conf/mosquitto.conf file in EBS volume of host EC2 instance.

But still it is giving this below error

> 1692960986: Error: Unable to open config file /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.

Comment: I think the `sourcePath` for the volume should be `/conf/mosquitto.conf` based on what you said

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I got confused with mountPoints and sourcePaths. I switched values of those, and it is working fine.